# My Bootstrap modal is currently not working in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, bootstrap-5

This is the code of the EventList

```
<template>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <div class="event-list" style="background-color: #0992A4;">
    <div class="container my-5">
      <div class="row">
        <div v-for="event in events" :key="event.title" class="col-md-12 mb-4">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <img :src="event.imageUrl" alt="Event Image" class="img-fluid" style="max-width: 100%;" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">{{ event.title }}</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">{{ event.description.substring(0, 200) }}...</p>
                  <p class="card-text">Prijs: €{{ event.price }}</p>
                  <p class="card-text">Datum: {{ event.date }}</p>
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" @click="openModal(event)">Meer informatie</button>
                  <button class="btn btn-warning" @click="openRegistrationModal">Aanmelden</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <EventModal :selectedEvent="selectedEvent" :is-active="modalActive" @close="closeModal" />
  <EventRegistrationModal :isActive="registrationModalActive" :selectedEvent="selectedEvent" @close="closeRegistrationModal" />
</template>


<script>
import Event from "@/models/event";
import EventModal from "@/components/EventModal";
import EventRegistrationModal from "@/components/EventRegistrationModal";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      events: [
        // Some events here (not important for the question)
      ],
      selectedEvent: null,
      registrationModalActive: false,
      modalActive: false,
    };
  },
  components: {
    EventModal,
    EventRegistrationModal,
  },

  methods: {
    openModal(event){
      this.selectedEvent = event;
      this.modalActive = true;
    },

    closeModal(){
      this.selectedEvent = null;
      this.modalActive = false;
    },

    openRegistrationModal(){
      this.registrationModalActive = true;
    },

    closeRegistrationModal(){
      this.registrationModalActive =false;
    }
  }
};


</script>

<style>
  @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

  .card-body{
    font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
  }

</style>
```

This is the EventModal

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" :class="{ 'd-block': showModal }">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" v-if="selectedEvent">{{ selectedEvent.title }}</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" @click="closeModal">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p v-if="selectedEvent"><strong>Beschrijving:</strong> {{ selectedEvent.description }}</p>
            <p v-if="selectedEvent"><strong>Prijs:</strong> €{{ selectedEvent.price }}</p>
            <p v-if="selectedEvent"><strong>Datum:</strong> {{ selectedEvent.date }}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="closeModal">Sluiten</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    selectedEvent: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showModal: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    closeModal() {
      this.showModal = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The current idea is that the "Meer informatie" button opens the modal. Currently it just loads in the information from the event that is clicked. As seen here
[image]

The only thing that has semi-worked so far is adding this to the modal. Now we load in info with "Meer informatie" but open the modal with this button, but we only want "Meer informatie" to do all of that.

```
<button @click="showModal = true" class="btn btn-primary">Bekijk Evenement</button>
```

Comment: You have a prop on the `<EventModal>` element `:is-active="modalActive"` but there's no `isActive` prop in the EventModal component.  The value of `modalActive` is therefore not being passed to your modal.